# jconsole from Zulu doesn't work

Tags: azul-zulu, azure-zulu

I have Zulu 7.1.0.0 installed on latest MS Windows (2012r2). I can run terminal and server apps, but executing jconsole produces no result: no UI shown, no error messages.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azul Zulu up to version **7.1** required headless mode to be disabled in order to run UI applications. E.g.:

```
jconsole -J-Djava.awt.headless=false
```

Starting from Zulu **7.2**, headful mode is enabled by default so the `-Djava.awt.headless=false` argument is no longer needed.